# Hot reload doesn't hot-reload

Tags: react-native, hot-reload

I activated hot reloading and it's not hot-reloading.  When I make a change to any Javascript file, the Packager re-runs and the simulator puts a gray bar at the top saying "Hot reloading..." for a few seconds.

But that is it.  The behavior of the app doesn't change and the debugger (in Chrome) shows the unchanged file.

I'm somewhat at a loss.  Any idea how I could track this down?

Comment: I have the same experience. Only sometimes does it hot-reload. My approach is to just press **F5** and then not think more about it ...

Answer (score 1):

The hot reloading according to the developers is still in development phase and is quite buggy. You could always do a full re-run of the app but the hot reload works like a charm sometimes and not at all otherwise.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html

> Word of warning: because JavaScript is a very stateful language, hot reloading cannot be perfectly implemented. In practice, we found out that the current setup is working well for a large amount of usual use cases and a full reload is always available in case something gets messed up.