# Yarn hot reload not hot reloading

Tags: yarnpkg, hot-reload

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734382/hot-reload-doesnt-hot-reload) question about yarn not hot reloading, but it doesn't answer my question.

I'm using macOS Catalina, and I'm using `yarn start` to see the change I make on my project. It has always hot reloaded, but suddenly, it stopped working and it's never hot reloading by itself anymore. I now have to manually reload and scroll down every time I make a change that I need to see.

Does anyone know a fix for this?